# Get Rid of Error Message - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, error-handling

When I do the try/catch method in my vb.net project I will try the code I want and when it can't do it, i make a message box right after the catch method. The thing is that it will show the message box, and then another message from the program itself. Like for example, I have here a MySQLException, and when i click ok on the message box, it will show another one right after showing the exception itself. How would I be able to get rid of this so the user doesn't have to see this, and the program can continue.

Thanks,

kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're actually getting more than one exception.  Have you checked the stack traces for both errors?

What I think is happening is that your first function is throwing the MySQLException and then returning nothing.  You're then probably getting a NullReferenceException from whatever made the call to the database.

Your best bet is to not catch some many exceptions.  Your data layer should be free of Try/Catch blocks unless you're trying to cater for something very specific.  Your business layer should then catch any other non-general exceptions that occur specific to the functionality there.  Finally, your application layer should be handling all of your general exceptions and reporting on them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should only display one message. Make sure your original message is coming from a statement after the `Try`.

```
Try
  code
Catch ex as exception
  call msgbox (ex.message)
end try
```